# How to format TimeObject with 12-hour AM/PM format?

Tags: date-and-time

`Interpreter["Time"]` does the opposite of what I want, convert a date or time in AM/PM format to 24-hour, but is there any way to display `DateObject` and `TimeObject` with using AM/PM?

Comment: Use [`DateString[DateObject[...], ...]`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) with an appropriate format string?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer:

> `but is there any way to display DateObject and TimeObject with using AM/PM?`

```
timestamps = 
 DatePlus[DateObject[{2023, 1, 1, 5, 0, 0}], Quantity[#, "Hours"]] & /@
   Range[24]

DateString[#, {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour12", ":", 
    "Minute", ":", "Second", " ", "AMPM"}] & /@ timestamps
```

[image]

Comment: Accepted, but I was hoping there was a way to change the display format of a DateObject to avoid the need to interpret it again for calculations.

Comment: `DateObject`, being an object, is for computations not presentation. For display, the `DateString` is provided. May be there is an `internal` or `developer` function to force its appearance. I am unaware of it though. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

```
toDateTimeString12H[date_DateObject] := (
 datetime24h = DateList[date];
 hour = DateValue[datetime24h, "Hour"];
 datetime12h = ReplacePart[datetime24h, 4 -> Mod[hour, 12] /. 0 -> 12];
 DateString[
  DateObject[datetime12h,   
   DateFormat -> {"Year", "-", "Month", "-", "Day", " ", "Hour", ":", 
    "Minute", ":", "Second", If[hour < 12, " am", " pm"]}
  ]
 ]
)
(*Testing*)
toDateTimeString12H[DatePlus[Now, Quantity[#, "Hours"]]] & /@ Range[24] // Column
(*Output*)
```

[image]